# How to enter values in text box by using Selenium Automation-Android Emulator on Sauce Labs

Tags: android, selenium

While automating android emulator on sauce labs I cant enter the value "123-456-0789" in the textbox even though I have used the following code;

```
 //I have checked the web element also.
 driver.findElement(By.id("PatientPhone")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.id("PatientPhone")).sendKeys("123-456-0789");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Javascript executor and set the value to its attribute.
use the following code. hope it will work fine.

```
  JavascriptExecutor exe = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  String query="$('#PatientPhone').attr('value','123-456-0789')";
  exe.executeScript(query,"");
```